# Is there a way to make my image background darker so my text will show up better?

Tags: css, background

first question so hopefully I am asking it properly.

I am working on a mainpage and have a background that is an image.  I am trying to darken it so my text will show up better.  I believe it's called overlaying the image. I have looked up how to do this but I am having trouble converting their code with mine.  Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(https://worldstrides.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Columbia.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

Comment: sure, sorry for the late response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply a `linear-gradient` to the background. This creates a layer on top of the background image which can be any color you want.

```css
 body{
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(39, 71, 118, 0.6), rgba(39, 71, 118, 0.6)), url("https://worldstrides.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Columbia.jpg");
 }
```

The code above will create a blue transparent layer on top of your image.

[Jsfiddle (example)](https://jsfiddle.net/ewq6yojc/)

Answer (score 0):

You have the text itself

```
.text{
    color:(any dark color can go in here) 


}

<p class = text>text<p>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question as he is trying to set the background to a darker color and you are making the text a darker color.